# callback is not a function full calendar resources

Tags: asp.net, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm trying to get the resources of full calendar as a function

```
 callback is not a function
```

and this is my code

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    resources: function (callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../sales/Calendar.aspx/getResources',
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var resourceObjects = [];
                $(data.d).each(function () {
                    resourceObjects.push({
                        id: this.id,
                        title: this.title,
                    });
                });
                callback(resourceObjects);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('There was an error');
            }
        });
    }

});
```

the event function is working but the problem with resources function.